# Enable NetSuite Sandbox SuiteCommerce site

Tags: netsuite, web-hosting, suitecommerce

I am stuck in a requirement where the client needs their NS sandbox SuiteCommerce website up and running. He is using SuiteCommerce Advanced.

I need to setup the sandbox website such that its domain becomes `sandbox.livesite.com`. I already got the CNAME required to set in GoDaddy. The CNAME is `sandbox.livesite.com.hosting.netsuite.com`. As am not an expert in web hosting, I have no idea what to do in the domain hosting site.

I tried creating a sub-domain record with prefix "sandbox" under `www.livesite.com` domain in GoDaddy, as well as creating a CNAME record, but still in NetSuite the domain record status shows "Waiting for DNS configuration".

I would appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a CNAME record in your DNS provider settings (GoDaddy) with the name "sandbox" and value "sandbox.livesite.com.hosting.netsuite.com".  Not sure what you mean by "I tried creating a sub-domain record with prefix "sandbox" under [www.livesite.com](http://www.livesite.com) domain". There should be no www in your CNAME record.  Instead, what you are doing with this CNAME is creating a sub-domain of "livesite.com" - *not* "www.livesite.com".  Remember to give time for the new settings to propagate through the network of DNS servers - this can take, in rare cases, up to 48 hours.  Usually more like 1-2 hours.